# What's the name of notation?

Tags: notation

Could anyone tell me what's the name of this notation? I mean all those () [] {} brackets? Where can I find theirs meaning?

```
CREATE TABLE Nazwa_relacji
({nazwa_atrybutu typ_atrybutu [{NOT NULL} | NULL]
[DEFAULT wartość_domyślna]
[{ograniczenie_atrybutu [ ...]}] [, ...]}
[,{ograniczenie_relacji [, ...]}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simplified use of [Backus–Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notation. BNF is very common in technical documentation, because it's an efficient way of describing most programming language syntax. The symbols in your example mean:

- `[]` optional items
- `{}` a group of items, normally used in conjunction with `...`
- `...` marks where the preceding items in the group repeat
- `|` either/or

Any symbols not defined in BNF are taken literally, e.g. `()`.